# Join RDD and get min value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have multiple rdd's and want to get the common words by joining it and get the minimum count .So I Join and get it by below code :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Join app")
x = sc.parallelize([("spark", 1), ("hadoop", 4)])
y = sc.parallelize([("spark", 2), ("hadoop", 5)])
joined = x.join(y).map(lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1]))).reduceByKey(lambda (x,y,z) : (x,y)  if y<=z else (x,z))
final = joined.collect()
print "Join RDD -> %s" % (final)
```

But this throws below error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

So I am inputiing a tuple instead of a number .Not sure which is causing it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you want from output of map function?. because first of map  is returning String and second is returning as tuple of the second rdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.join(other, numPartitions=None)`: Return an RDD containing all pairs of elements with matching keys in C{self} and C{other}. Each pair of elements will be returned as a (k, (v1, v2)) tuple, where (k, v1) is in C{self} and (k, v2) is in C{other}.

Therefore you have a tuple as second element:

```
In [2]: x.join(y).collect()
Out[2]: [('spark', (1, 2)), ('hadoop', (4, 5))]
```

Solution :

```
x = sc.parallelize([("spark", 1), ("hadoop", 4)])
y = sc.parallelize([("spark", 2), ("hadoop", 5)])
joined = x.join(y)
final = joined.map(lambda x: (x[0], min(x[1])))
final.collect()
>>> [('spark', 1), ('hadoop', 4)]
```